# Why my C program never reach EOF

Tags: c

I am learning C with `"The C programming Language"` book and in one of the examples i have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;

    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%1d\n", nc);
}
```

But this program never reach EOF and i don't know why

Comment: 1. I think `main` wants to have a return type. 2.  think you want to use `%ld` as placeholder

Comment: More generally, sometimes standard input just never ends. (User input never signals EOF, file is `/dev/zero` or `/dev/urandom`)

Comment: It's usually better to look at the current keystroke or character input than EOF from stdin.

Comment: Did you actually send it an EOF character when running it interactively? On Unix/Linux and MacOS/X that would be `CTRL-D` and on Windows and DOS `CTRL-Z` ...

Comment: you could just replace EOF with '\n' if you want